# How to use delegate call with or without arguments functions?

Tags: delegatecall

Below is my contract:

```
contract A{

    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    function put() payable public {
        balances[msg.sender] = msg.value;
    }

    function get(address lucky) public {
        require(msg.sender != lucky);

        if (!lucky.call.value(balances[msg.sender])()) {
            revert();
        }

        balances[msg.sender] = 0;
    }

    function() payable public {}
}
```

Now, I need to invoke the get function and the put function from another contract. Get function is not payable and need an address argument whereas the put function is the `payable` function and needs scope of `msg.value` only.

I tried the below code snippet but it all fails, can someone guide what I am doing wrong here?

```
import "browser/A.sol";

contract Attack {

    address bf = 0xdd1F635Dfb144068f91D430c76f4219088Af9E64;

    function attackBayFountain() public payable {
        // this should send msg.value to the put function
        require(bf.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("put()"))));

        // this should call get function of contract A with address of the Attack contract as argument
        require(bf.delegatecall(bytes4( keccak256 ("get(address)")), address(this)) ); 
    }

    // fallback function - where the magic happens
    function () payable public{
    }
}
```

Comment: If your intention is to delegatecall from Attack to A it will not work. With delegatecall you are executing A functions in Attack storage, for that to work both have to have compatible data layout (ie the same variables in the same order). Also you will modify Attack's storage not A's storage which may not be what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to make call from “me -user 1” to “Attack” and “Attack” shall execute “put and get function of contract A”, but msg.sender should be “me-user 1” and not “Attack” when “put and get” function of “A” is called.

Comment: That is not possible. It will be a major security issue if a contract can impersonate a user.